# Extracting the same string structures with regex

Tags: java, regex

I'm running the next code:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(<http:.*>)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("<http:fluffy1@cisco.com>,<http:fluffy2@cisco.com>");
    if (m.find()) {
        int groupCount = m.groupCount();
        for(int i = 0; i < groupCount; i++){
            String groupValue = m.group(i);
            System.out.println(groupValue);
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("nothing was fined");
    }
```

And as output I have only one group value: "http:fluffy1@cisco.com,http:fluffy2@cisco.com"
But I expect that there should be two groups :
Group_1: http:fluffy1@cisco.com
Group_2: http:fluffy2@cisco.com

How should I change my regex to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Change to non-greedy `*` maybe? `<http:.*?>`

Comment: Or better yet, use a negated character class that matches anything but `>` instead of `.` :  `<http:[^>]*>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not group. It will be group if your pattern look like "(http:.*)(http:.*)". Group is expression between parentheses.
Try this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(<http:([^>]+)>)");
Matcher m = p.matcher("<http:fluffy1@cisco.com>,<http:fluffy2@cisco.com>");
while (m.find()) {
    String groupValue = m.group(1); // m.group(2) for email only without http: and <>
    System.out.println(groupValue);
}
```

Comment: Why group_2 match email?

Comment: first group - expression within first parentheses - (<http:([^>]+)>) and
second group - expression within second parentheses - ([^>]+)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below code:

```
   Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(<http:.*?>)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("<http:fluffy1@cisco.com> , <http:fluffy2@cisco.com>");
    if (m.find()) {
        int groupCount = m.groupCount();
        for(int i = 0; i <= groupCount; i++){
            String groupValue = m.group(i);
            System.out.println("Group("+i+")"+groupValue);
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("nothing was fined");
    }
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

As @user3783243 suggested in one of the comments, you could change the regex to a non-greedy (lazy) evaluation, by adding a `?` to the `*` quantifier:

> *? Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)

The resulting regex would be:

```
(<http:.*?>)
```

Here's the test for it: https://regex101.com/r/7751x9/1